# Can [information-display] be burninated on MSO and SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Is there seriously any use for [information-display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/information-display) on SO, or [information-display](/questions/tagged/information-display) on meta? I propose they they shall be KILLED WITH FIRE.

Comment: For meta, it could either be removed or replaced by "design".

Comment: Well, done for meta.

Comment: Well, done for SO. Now we wait for the oven to get to temp.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was completed some time ago.